# How can I ignore sound played by my app when looking for activity from the microphone in Air using ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, air, microphone

I am making an app using Air and AS3 where I am looking for noise from the microphone. At the same time I am playing sound through the speakers of the phone, but I want to ignore these sounds from the input of the microphone.

I want to know when some external source is making noise and then act upon it, but now my triggers fire when the sound I am playing myself get too loud.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mic.setUseEchoSuppression(true); 
mic.setLoopback(false);
```

(In this order).

Comment: I am not getting this to work :/
What I am trying to do is determine if any other source of sound that the sound playing from the device itself is present.
I want to ignore the sound playing from my app, and then detect if any other noises are present. mic.activityLevel still rises a lot when my sound from the device is getting louder.